# Using GeoTools to open Esri File Geodatabase (FileGDB)?

Tags: file-geodatabase, geotools, file-geodatabase-api

How can I open an Esri File Geodatabase (FileGDB) in GeoTools?

Comment: Try the ogr plugin

Comment: But that only works with JNI. Is there a plain java solution as well?

Comment: You have to use the esri dll AFAIK

Comment: The File Geodatabase API was only released as a C++ library. Without a Java port, a pure Java solution is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243746/geotools-open-esri-file-geodatabase-filegdb#comment381361_243746):

> The File Geodatabase API was only released as a C++ library. Without a
>   Java port, a pure Java solution is not possible.